# Very infrequent Excel crash

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, crash, microsoft-excel-2010, event-log

Have 1 user who keeps experiencing an Excel crash when sorting data.

It is very infrequent and as of yet i've not done any serious troubleshooting, just an Office repair.

Event log reports the following:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          07/03/2012 10:57:27
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      luke-p
Description:
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.6112.5000, time stamp: 0x4e9b2bb3
Faulting module name: mso.dll, version: 14.0.6112.5000, time stamp: 0x4e9b27af
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x003e9906
Faulting process id: 0xfe8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccfc5104d807e5
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\mso.dll
Report Id: 5370db34-6844-11e1-84fd-2c27d71b430a
```

Looking around i can't find many solutions, or much information regarding this error.

We have several PC's exactly the same PC's (HP Pro 3305 MT) daily and the problem only occurs on 1 of them.

Dump of Event log errors: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/Luke%20Excel%20Crash%20Eventlogs.txt

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling excel? Seems like the natural thing to do if there are no add-ins and it happens in workbooks without macros, could be a function of the application that's corrupted. Try to reinstall

Comment: I've done a repair currently but as it's happening so infrequently i've not taken any more drastic steps! Next will be a Office uninstall, repair of Windows followed by an Office reinstall...

Comment: Be sure to clean the registry between installs, and to remove user data

Comment: I'm **very** wary of 'Registry cleaners' as we have a 3rd party bespoke software solution here which has been known to break due to `invalid registry keys being removed` by registry 'fixes'. Any programs you would recommend?

Comment: I use [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), you can just scan and remove MS Office-identified keys, or choose to remove none of them. You can also backup changes before you remove anything.

Comment: the way they are sorting is not different in anyway? How they select, what they are doing in general? Key sequences?

Comment: Not from what i can tell, this user probably opens in excess of 100 excel documents a day (order processing) with lots of column sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be multiple issues with working with.xls files (97-2003) in Compatibility Mode.  Try having the user save the file as an .xlsx.  This eliminated the crashing errors for my users.

Comment: This has certainly lowered the amount of errors, but as for an actual 'solution' i'm reticent to accept it. I have a mixed network and theres no way I'm changing all Office versions to 2007/2010! Not to mention the problems with the Office Compatiblity Pack on older versions if we just used the newer formats...

Answer (score 1):

The problem may originate from an Excel add-in or a macro. Try starting Excel in Safe Mode (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while startup). The Safe Mode will disable all add-ins and macros. If Excel works fine in Safe Mode, try disabling add-ins one by one from `File > Options > Add-Ins` to determine the guilty one.

Comment: No add-ins and the error has occured with excel documents with (and without) macro's. It's so infequent (happened 3-4 times in 3 months) and unrepeatable that starting in safe-mode hasn't been attempted yet!